# Sorting json objects based on time as the order after parsing them

Tags: android, json, parsing

Here is the code:
        I want to sort them based on time and/or date:
        They are already displayed, just not in order. For now, what I have are codes that parse json objects into xml. All I want to do is parsing them based on time and/or date. The item below is the example of JSON file where there are different dates and time(2 min ago, 5 min ago etc)

```
try {
 // Create the root JSONObject from the JSON string.
 JSONObject jsonRootObject = new JSONObject(myjsonstring);

 //Get the instance of JSONArray that contains JSONObjects
 JSONArray jsonArray = jsonRootObject.getJSONArray("Postdetails");

 //Iterate the jsonArray and print the info of JSONObjects
 for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
  //Collections.sort(jsonValues);
  String text = jsonObject.optString("number_of_likes").toString();
  String minute = jsonObject.optString("min_ago").toString();
  //float salary = Float.parseFloat(jsonObject.optString("salary").toString());
  time += minute + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n" + "\n";
  data += text;

 }

 output.setText(data);
 timeago.setText(time);


} catch (JSONException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

JSON file:

```
{
  "Postdetails": [
    {
      "min_ago": "2 min ago",
      "number_of_likes": "63",
      "number_of_comments": "92",
      "date": "7 March 2017"
    },
    {
      "min_ago": "5 min ago",
      "number_of_likes": "72",
      "number_of_comments": "123",
      "date": "7 March 2017"
    },
    {
      "min_ago": "9 min ago",
      "number_of_likes": "123",
      "number_of_comments": "9123",
      "date": "10 March 2017"
    },
    {
      "min_ago": "6 min ago",
      "number_of_likes": "133",
      "number_of_comments": "9123",
      "date": "9 March 2017"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: By the time you extract the date to order them, you've already parsed it. What may make sense for your app (or not, don't know your use case) is to cache the results after first parse, probably by using some kind of DB, but maybe even this can be overkill if your data structure is as simple as this one.

Comment: how do I cache the result?

Comment: Moved my answers to a question, see below.

Answer (score 0):

By the time you extract the date to order them, you've already parsed it. What may make sense for your app (or not, don't know your use case) is to cache the results after first parse, probably by using some kind of DB, but maybe even this can be overkill if your data structure is as simple as this one.

In case you want to follow the caching strategy, you can use a database like SQLite (use [Room](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/room.html) on top of it to make access easier, or some other ORM), or [Realm](https://realm.io/products/realm-mobile-database/), which has plenty of tutorials online. There are many more, but those two are the ones I find easier to use.